# How to copy files on a CMD on LAN (windows xp)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

hello I don't know about this but I found this on Internet cafe but I don't have enough knowledge on how .bat files works, So I want to know how to copy files like this display.
And the files is already shared so that I can copy. All PC don't have password. Just directly log-in to desktop.

```
Input location to copy: \\PC1\Steam\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta
Input location to paste: D:\Games\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta
```

then it will alert me if done. The files will be overwrite and paste all data.

I don't know the code of copying too and I search too many still cant understand. I just want to use this on my internet cafe so that I don't update games anymore on every PC. Because copying on directly network is my costumer don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Copy -y "source" "destination".

With the quotes if there are spaces in the path.  Also, if copy does not want to copy from the network unc, then first connect to the unc using "net use".

Comment: that IS the code. Just insert the right `source` and `destination`